# How to use Windows 7 APIs in an application that should also run on Windows XP

Tags: winapi

I'd like to use some functions that are only available in Windows 7 or higher in my application but I also want my app to remain compatible with Windows XP. The app should check at runtime if at least Windows 7 is available and offer some advanced features (like Media Foundation support) in that case.

Is the only way to do this to manually check for Windows 7-only DLLs using `LoadLibrary` and then importing all the functions I need using `GetProcAddress()`? This would be very inconvenient but I don't see any other way. Statically linking against Windows 7+ DLLs will cause the application to refuse to start on XP because of missing DLLs so this won't work. But doesn't the Windows SDK offer some more convenient technique for programmers who want to remain compatible with older Windows versions and optionally use features of newer Windows versions?

Note that my application is written in plain C so I'm looking for a solution in C.

Comment: or explicit call LoadLibrary + GetProcAddress or use delayload

Answer (score 4):

1. Don't ever check for OS versions. Check for available features instead.
2. The most convenient way to keep your code compatible with earlier versions of Windows while still allowing it to opt-in to newer features is to use delay-loading of modules (see [Linker Support for Delay-Loaded DLLs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/linker-support-for-delay-loaded-dlls)). This allows you to benefit from import resolution as you would with compile-time dynamic linking, yet allows you to respond to import failures at runtime.

Comment: So how do I check for available features, e.g. how would I check for the presence of Media Foundation? Should I try to open `mfplat.dll` and import `MFStartup` and if that succeeds, assume that Media Foundation is available?

Comment: [MFStartup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/mfapi/nf-mfapi-mfstartup) appears to be available starting with Windows XP SP 2. Though the outlined procedure would be a feature test (as opposed to an OS version test).

Comment: But how would such a feature test would look like for Media Foundation? How would I test for Media Foundation being available? The only thing I can think of is what I described in comment 1.

Comment: @Andreas API that works on XP doesn't magically stop working simply because Microsoft no longer support XP. Please refer to the actual test.  Similar case : https://stackoverflow.com/a/31974560/11128312

Answer (score -1):

There are 2 options:

1. `LoadLibrary` / `GetProcAddress`. It is not so inconvenient - you can define and assign function pointers and use them like normal functions.
2. Compile 2 versions for XP and 7. The installer chooses the right executable or XP version is started by default and it runs second executable if OS is Win7.

Comment: *you can define and assign function pointers and use them like normal functions.* - better define `PVOID __imp_funcname;` (for *x64*) or `DD __imp__funcname@<numargs*4>` in asm for x86 and init it to actual pointers at runtime. also possible use delay-load some library

Comment: The second option is not an scalable option. Consider replacing it with a real option: [Linker Support for Delay-Loaded DLLs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/linker-support-for-delay-loaded-dlls).

Comment: @IInspectable What is the problem with option 2? Many apps have 32 and 64 bit executables.

Comment: The Windows SDK provides type definitions that allow you to compile **the same code** to target both 32-bit and 64-bit targets. The Windows SDK doesn't provide **anything** that would allow you to compile the same code to target an OS that provides any given API as well as an OS that doesn't. Do you see how those are different? Do you understand why one of those doesn't scale?

Comment: @IInspectable I was trying to say that in case with 32/64 bit versions, you have 2 different executables or installations. It is not a big problem to use the same organization for such program which has to run on XP and Win7 (with extra API-s). Maybe not ideal solution but simple and working.

Comment: You are missing the key difference: Compiling a 32-bit and 64-bit release of your application is something you set up once, and the compiler does the rest. Targeting different OS versions with different available features means writing *conditional* code. Every time a developer adds or updates code they will have to evaluate availability of the system services they plan to use, and potentially come up with solutions for every single targeted OS version. This is the opposite of a one-time setup.

Comment: @IInspectable "Targeting different OS versions with different available features means writing conditional code." - read the original question above. Writing conditional code is obvious. The author asks how to do it.

Comment: @i486: Having two different executables is a rather ugly solution IMHO. Of course I'd like to have a single executable that can support both, XP and Windows 7.

Comment: Again, you are missing the point. Sure, targeting different API sets means writing different code. With delay-loading you can consolidate the differences into one or two functions (as opposed to spreading it across your code base), **and** wind up with a single executable that can run across all of your targets.